# Postgres returns SQL state: 22001 when copying data to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Searching on google the SQL state: 22001 is because:

> the sql statement specifies a
>   string that is too long

but both tables have the same definition of the column.

this is the table i want to have the data copied:

```
CREATE TABLE wise_estado
(
  id_estado serial NOT NULL,
 >> cvgeo_estado character varying(2),<<
  nombre_estado character varying
)
```

this the table with data i want to copy:

```
CREATE TABLE estados
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
 >> "CVE_ENT" character varying(2),<<
  "NOM_ENT" character varying(80),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
  CONSTRAINT estados_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

my SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO wise_estado ( cvgeo_estado, nombre_estado)
SELECT  'CVE_ENT', 'NOM_ENT'
FROM estados
```

What i'm missing in my SQL statement?

Comment: `'CVE_ENT'` is a character constant, not a column name: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending string literals instead of field names in your SQL statement. Instead:

```
INSERT INTO wise_estado ( cvgeo_estado, nombre_estado)
SELECT  "CVE_ENT", "NOM_ENT"
FROM estados;
```

Or, more succintly:

```
INSERT INTO wise_estado ( cvgeo_estado, nombre_estado)
SELECT  CVE_ENT, NOM_ENT
FROM estados
```

Comment: Unquoted identifiers are folded to lowercase in Postgres, not to uppercase as in the SQL standard; the quotes are necessary here.